# Wrong figures numbering - Package caption Error: Continued 'figure' after 'table'

Tags: latex

Hello I am having a problem with the numbering of figures using Latex, I am getting this error message:

> Package caption Error: Continued 'figure' after 'table'

This is my code:

```
\begin{table}
\centering
\subfloat[Tabla1\label{tab:Tabla1}]{
\small
\begin{tabular}{ | c | c | c | c | c |}
\hline
\multicolumn{5}{|c|}{\textbf{Tabla 1}} \\ \hline
...
...
\end{tabular}
}
\qquad
\subfloat[Tabla2\label{tab:Tabla2}]{
\small
\begin{tabular}{ | c | c | c | c | c |}
\hline
\multicolumn{5}{|c|}{\textbf{Tabla 2}} \\ \hline
...
...
\end{tabular}
}
\caption{These are tables}
\label{tab:Tables}
\end{table}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\subfloat[][Figure 1]{\label{fig:fig1}\includegraphics[width = 14cm]{fig1}}
\qquad
\subfloat[][Figure 2]{\label{fig:fig2}\includegraphics[width = 14cm]{fig2}}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[t]  
\ContinuedFloat
\subfloat[][Figure 2]{\label{fig:fig3}\includegraphics[width = 14cm]{fig3}}
\caption{Those are figures}
\label{fig:Figures}
\end{figure}
\newpage
```

What I want to do, it is to have this configuration:

Table

Table

Figure 1

Figure 2

Figure 3

Since Figure 1 and Figure 2 are too big to fit vertically I want the Figure 3 to be alone in another page that's why I have the \ContinuedFloat.

Externally looks fine but the problem is the numbering, I am getting for the Figures the number 5.2, that is the same number that a Figure I have before (The correct number should be 5.3).

However if I try to reference the figures:

```
\ref{fig:fig1}, \ref{fig:fig2} y \ref{fig:fig2}
```

I get:

```
5.3a, 5.3b y 5.2c
```

The two first right the last one wrong.

I have been stuck with this for hours any ideas?.

Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need a `\caption` command in your first figure environment. Otherwise there is nothing to "continue". A figure only receives a number when the `\caption` command is executed.

Comment: Hard to make a short and better answer, you are my hero tonight!